# Direction of Electromotive Force

Tags: electricity

Can we determine the direction of emf from the direction of current?

I know  current exists from higher potential to lower potential and through this we can guess which terminal is at higher potential and which is at lower potential but question remain same:  what is the direction of emf?

A simple explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: `direction of emf...` what? It's the line-integral of the tangential component of any "_influence_", the force, per unit charge along a certain curve or specifically around the wire. Can you tell me how to specify a direction?

Comment: Also, please don't use punctuation marks unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition Of EMF** (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force)) :

> Electromotive force, also called emf, is the voltage developed by any
>   source of electrical energy such as a battery or dynamo. It is
>   generally defined as the electrical potential for a source in a
>   circuit. A device that supplies electrical energy is called
>   electromotive force or emf. Emfs convert chemical, mechanical, and
>   other forms of energy into electrical energy.The product of such a
>   device is also known as emf.

So, as you can see from the definition, EMF is a scalar quantity and has no direction. However, EMF is the cause of potential difference. And as you rightly said: "*Current flows from higher potential to lower potential*".

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the concept of current is a logical construct.  That electrons are negatively charged, and so they are moving along wires in the opposite direction to the logical current.